# substring a text with html tags using css break word or something?

Tags: javascript, css

```
var txt = 'Some texts, html tags & all values i can enter through text box';
txt= txt.substring(0,255)+'...';
```

Can i do this thing using css?

My problem is if `txt` contains HTML tags, after doing a sub string the closing tag gets missing and it will break.

Comment: Why are u doing a substring(). What is the expected result?

Comment: Please explain the issue you are having.

Comment: You can use CSS -> `text-overflow:ellipsis;`

Comment: Can you give an example in "jsfiddle"

Comment: @AkhilSekharan the txt i get is a description i got from a text box with maxlength of 3072 . it accept characters , html tags special characters etc. i need to display ony 255 characters ony. and if i do a substring some html tag may get break because the closing tag will be removed in the deleted portion. and it breaked my next set of html because of the absence of closing tag..

Comment: thnk you every one for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But for this you should set `width` of element -

Try this CSS -

```
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
```

[See in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZmb4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

CSS will only work when you have to display the txt information on screen in some elements such as `<div>` or `<p>`

In order to make text appear with ellipses, try the following CSS properties

```
p{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're using jQuery, you can use it's `text()` function.

```
var txt = 'Some texts, html tags & all values i can enter through text box';
txt= txt.text().substring(0,255)+'...';
```

That will display all non-html elements.